# Как правильно записать?

Tags: правописание

Иди вперед, назад ни шагу - запомни это навсегда! Возобнови в себе отвагу, не падай духом никогда!

Answer (score 1):

Можно и Ваш вариант оставить, он вполне допустим.

Но лучше, наверное, оформить эти две части параллельно:

Иди вперед, назад ни шагу - запомни это навсегда! Возобнови в себе отвагу - не падай духом никогда!